# More jobs at Company X yields 404

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Companies that have more than one open job presents a link:

[image]

Here is an example company job posting:

https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/104658/senior-front-end-developer-crate-and-barrel?searchTerm=senior-front-end-developer-crate-and-barrel

That will take you to the job listing page.  Scroll down midway until you see the link "more jobs at Crate and Barrel".  Click that link...

But when you click that link you get a 404 everytime:

[image]

Comment: I don't even see the link. Did it get removed?

Comment: See it where?  I have posted it...

Comment: The "more jobs at" link. I only have a "We have 3 open jobs" button which does work.

Comment: Im not sure I follow if you go to this link: http://stackoverflow.com/jobs/104658/senior-front-end-developer-crate-and-barrel?searchTerm=senior-front-end-developer-crate-and-barrel and scroll towards the bottom you dont see the link that says "more jobs at Crate and Barrel" ?  The link is next to the "apply now" button found midway on that page (on the right side of that button).

Comment: So I go to the link you provided and click on "more jobs at Crate and Barrel", I do see 3 jobs posted. See image : http://imgur.com/a/jADCq

Comment: I do not see the link using Chrome Version 55.0.2883.87. The rest of the banner next to "Apply Now" is empty. However, I do see "We have 3 open jobs" on the RHS.

Comment: Very very strange I am running Chrome latest version and I don't have the same results as you guys.  What I have is what I posted.  I go to this link: http://stackoverflow.com/jobs/104658/senior-front-end-developer-crate-and-barrel?searchTerm=senior-front-end-developer-crate-and-barrel and go straight towards the middle section of the page there is an apply now button.  To the left of that button is a hyperlink about "more jobs at Crate and Barrel" clicking that gives me a 404.  Im also on Version 55.0.2883.87 m

Comment: For me, it's to the right of the `apply now` button, as shown in your screenshot.  I can't reproduce the bug though.  Copying the link location in FF50 gives me [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/crate-and-barrel?tabPreview=JobDetailMoreJobs#open-jobs), which, when clicked, redirects [here](http://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/crate-and-barrel), at least for me.  You could check each of those links in my comment to see if any of them separately reproduce the error for you.

Comment: The funny thing is though, that, depending on which of those links I click, even though it goes to the same web address, it gives a different `<title>` - one is `Preview - Stack Overflow`, and one is `Crate and Barrel Jobs & Careers - Stack Overflow`.

Comment: There is definetly some bugs here the title is wrong and no it still doesnt work for me.  This link: http://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/crate-and-barrel?tabPreview=JobDetailMoreJobs#open-jobs gives me a 404 (as shown in the screen shot).

Comment: Try the same while not logged in as user you are right now, that might make picture clear if this issue is user specific.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good catch, @JonH! The link was sending users to company page preview instead of the company page. This should be fixed now.

Comment: Worked for me - that was quick!